# Compare data from worksheet for insert or update to a database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel, xlsx

I have the ID, Description and Price columns in an excel then I use a FileUpload to charge the file but would have to read the ID each column and see if there one on the database Table Items where I have likewise ID, description, price then if the ID exists I compare the price and upgrade if this is different and the other case I insert in table with ID, description, and price of the excel when the ID not exists.

Some friend tell me about use "Transverse excel spreadsheet" but i can't see any example.

```html
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(FileUpload1.HasFile){
                string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
                OleDbConnection OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties= Excel 12.0;");
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", OleDbcon);
                OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
 
                OleDbcon.Open();
                DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. I would take the data from the Excel file and load the DataReader into a DataTable. Also, you could use a second DataTable to retrieve the data from the database. Once you have two DataTables loaded in memory you can easily apply your business logic to make comparisons.

```
    DataTable DT_Excel = new DataTable();
    DT_Excel.Load(DbDataReader);
    //Load data into a DataTable


    DataTable DT_DataBase = new DataTable();
    DT_DataBase = GetDataFromDatabase();

    //A simple loop to compare the data
    foreach (DataRow dtRow in DT_Excel.Rows) {
            DT_DataBase.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = " + dtRow.Item("ID");
            if (DT_DataBase.DefaultView.ToTable.Rows.Count > 0) {
                    //Do something if record is already in the databse
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some details?

Comment: In my database I have my table Item with ID_DB, Description_DB and Price_DB, and also I have my file Excel (xlsx) with three columns ID_E, Description_E, and Price_E,  Then I need to compare each cell in the ID_E column (Excel) with ID_DB .If it exists change Price_DB with Price_ID  and If not I create a new item in database ID_DB, Description_DB, Price_DB with the data ID_E, Description_E, Price_E. Thanks for your help